# PHP is it possible to change variable in function from another file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I have a wordpress theme which has the following php function:

```
class Layers_Form_Elements {

...

public function input( $args = array() ) {

...

// Switch our input type
switch( $input->type ) {

...

case 'rte' :
// Apply allowed tags list
$allow_tags = ( isset( $input->allow_tags ) && is_array( $input->allow_tags ) ? implode( ',' , $input->allow_tags ) : array() );

// Add custom button support
$allow_buttons = ( isset( $input->allow_buttons ) && is_array( $input->allow_buttons ) ? $input->allow_buttons : array( 'sep','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','createLink','insertOrderedList','insertUnorderedList','subscript','removeFormat','html' ) );

... 

break;

}

} // Class
```

I would like to use a custom plugin to change the value of $allowed_buttons - is this possible with php? I am reluctant to hard code this into the theme as I will loose my edits on update, but I want to know if it's possible to change a variable in a function from another php file?